# Term for researching one's own life in detail?

Tags: research-methods, terminology

I'm a bit obsessed about recording my own life in detail. I have pretty much all the dates of the main events and eras of my life since I was 7yo. I have also preserved documents, messages, people etc. related to those events and eras.

I wonder if anybody else is doing anything like this? 
And haven't found any specific term for it? That would help a lot to find people alike.

From genealogy perspective this kind of activity could be beneficial for future generations & historians as they would have much more data about the lives of ordinary people. Digitalization has changed a lot and future research will be much different than we are currently doing.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! I can think of several words used historically, but they are all limited by the format used by the recorder, whether diary, journal, scrapbook, or hoard :) . Perhaps autobiographer would do, although it is usually applied once curated material is published.

Comment: Autobiographer is the first term that comes to my mind too.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I commend you on diligently recording details of your own life.  But how you do *preserve people*? <wink>  Did you drop a word, perhaps, and you meant to say "from people" or "about people" related to those events?

Comment: Thanks for the answers!! Autobiographer really feels like the one that I was searching for. Got relevant results from Google search now as well ;) Mentioning those "historical formats" was helpful too.

Comment: @Jan Murphy By "preserving people" I meant writing down their names in order to remember them. Pretty sloppy language there, I admit...

Comment: I appreciate your self-answer, since SE comments are supposed to be for improving the question, not answering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Autobiographer" is a good and descriptive term for the person who's doing the activity described in the question.

Collecting dates, documents etc. is kind of "collecting material for one's autobiography" although nothing is published yet (or even never will be)

I answered to my own question but it was rephrased from comments by @bgviehle and @PolyGeo.